# startActivity from TileService or from a view when all activities are in the background(android)

Tags: android

precondition:

1. android Q
2. all my activities are in the background

Question 1:

I have a view in the foreground, when user click the view, I try to start an activity in android Q.
Here's my code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, BorderActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

It's not work and no crash happen. I get some logs.

> D ActivityTaskManagerServiceInjector: MIUILOG- Permission Denied Activity : Intent ...

Question 2:

I have a TileService and when user click the icon in the statusbar, I try to start an activity.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class QuickSettingService extends TileService {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivityAndCollapse(intent);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<service
    android:name=".service.QuickSettingService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

and i get same error:

> D ActivityTaskManagerServiceInjector: MIUILOG- Permission Denied Activity : Intent ...

How can I startActivity from background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found that there's a special permission in MIUI rom.
`permission:android.permission.START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND`

User has to turn on 'Display pop-up windows while running in the background' in the app settings. I can't request the permission when the app is running, and I even can't know if user is granted the permission to the app.

Comment: China Ashoe? I'm starting to wonder how Huawei and Xiaomi are allowed to call their devices "Android". They basically created a fork that's not adhereing to any standards anymore. This is just one example of many app breaking changes

Comment: @CaptainCrunch Samsung also uses this permission.